# JavaScript (or TypeScirpt) colon and vertical bar

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax

Digging in React sources I found this file: [ReactCurrentDispatcher.js](http://const%20ReactCurrentDispatcher%20=%20%7B%20%20%20/**%20%20%20%20*%20@internal%20%20%20%20*%20@type%20%7BReactComponent%7D%20%20%20%20*/%20%20%20current:%20(null:%20null%20%7C%20Dispatcher),%20%7D;). It has `js` extension but at the top there is `import type { ... }` declaration so it seems like this is actually compiled as typescript. But what is interesting is the contents:

```js
const ReactCurrentDispatcher = {
  /**
   * @internal
   * @type {ReactComponent}
   */
  current: (null: null | Dispatcher),
};
```

What is this `null : null | Dispatcher` thingy? Colon is not an operator in JavaScript, in fact it doesn't even seem to be valid JavaScript as it throws SyntaxError in the console. Neither is this valid TypeScript, it doesn't compile in ts playground. What is this?

Comment: I think they might be using https://flow.org/en/docs/react/

Comment: @chautelly oh didn't think about that, it seems that this is actually the reason. Thanks!